# How to pass the instance of the actual jFrame to other jFrame

Tags: java, swing, oop, jframe, actionlistener

I have two classes, and from the first jFrame1 (CotizacionGUI) I instantiate and make visible the other one (jFrame2), and I want to pass the instance of this jFrame1 (CotizacionGUI), to the other, in the constructor, to dispose it in an action triggered by the button at any moment...

```
public class CotizacionGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    public CotizacionGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }
    private void buttonCallFrame2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        BuscarCotizacionGUI bC = new BuscarCotizacionGUI(thisjFrameinstance);
        bC.setVisible();
    }  
}
```

And this is the Frame2 (BuscarCotizacionGUI), here is where I want to dispose the previous jFrame, triggered by the action performed event:

```
public class BuscarCotizacionGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public BuscarCotizacionGUI(final JFrame otherFrame) {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                otherFrame.dispose();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Can you help me guys please, I don't want to do it using other class, i want to pass the reference in the jFrame1, Thanks!

Comment: Using multiple JFrames in your application is a bad design. Always create only 1 JFrame (which is your main window) and use auxiliary JDialogs if needed.

Comment: yeah i already read that...but i want solutions, if its possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of first JFrame is always available to you in the same class as `this`

```
public class CotizacionGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    public CotizacionGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }
    private void buttonCallFrame2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        BuscarCotizacionGUI bC = new BuscarCotizacionGUI(this);
        bC.setVisible();
    }  
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks man, you save my life! ;) thats what i really need, a solution =D